# Redux forms: how to handle errors in form component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, redux-form

Now I have such error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (SubmissionError): Submit Validation Failed

  27 |       .catch(err => {
> 28 |         return ErrorHandler.raiseAnError(err);
  29 |       });
```

Here is my code:

**TractorForm.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import FormInput from "../Shared/FormInput";
import GlobalConst from "../GlobalConst";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import SelectInput from "../Shared/SelectInput";
import ErrorHandler from "../ErrorHandler";

const manufacturers = ["DAF", "VOLVO", "SCANIA", "MAN", "IVECO"];

class TractorFormWrapper extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: false,
    isSubmitted: false
  };

  onFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ isSubmitted: true });
    if (this.props.valid) {
      this.setState({ loading: true });
      this.props
        .handleSubmit(e)
        .then(() => alert("is ok!"))
        .catch(err => {
          return ErrorHandler.raiseAnError(err);
        });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { submitText, error } = this.props;
    const { loading, isSubmitted } = this.state;
    const formClassNames = loading ? "ui form loading" : "ui form";
    return (
      <form className={formClassNames} onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
        <div className="ui grid fields">
          <div className="sixteen wide eight wide computer column">
            <SelectInput
              name="manufacturer"
              type="text"
              label="Производитель"
              validations={[GlobalConst.REQUIRED]}
              isSubmitted={isSubmitted}
              values={manufacturers}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="sixteen wide eight wide computer column">
            <FormInput
              name="model"
              type="text"
              label="Модель"
              validations={[GlobalConst.REQUIRED]}
              isSubmitted={isSubmitted}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="sixteen wide column">
            <FormInput
              name="description"
              type="textarea"
              label="Описание"
              isSubmitted={isSubmitted}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        {error && (
          <div className="ui red message">
            <strong>{error}</strong>
          </div>
        )}

        <div className="ui fluid buttons">
          <button
            className="ui primary button"
            type="submit"
            disabled={loading}
          >
            {submitText}
          </button>

          <Link to="/tractors" className="ui button">
            Отмена
          </Link>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

let TractorForm = {};

TractorForm.propTypes = {
  submitText: PropTypes.string
};

TractorForm.defaultProps = {
  submitText: "Отправить"
};

TractorForm = reduxForm({
  form: "tractor"
})(TractorFormWrapper);

export default TractorForm;
```

**TractorAdd.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TractorForm from "./TractorForm";
import TractorApi from "./TractorApi";
import { toast } from "react-semantic-toasts";
import ErrorHandler from "../ErrorHandler";

class TractorAdd extends Component {
  state = {};

  submit = values =>
    TractorApi.create(values).then(
      () => {
        toast({
          type: "success",
          icon: "truck",
          title: "Тягач создан",
          description: ""
        });
        this.props.history.push("/tractors");
      },
      error => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TractorForm onSubmit={this.submit} submitText="Создать" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TractorAdd;
```

**ErrorHandler.js**

```
import { SubmissionError } from "redux-form";

export default {
  raiseAnError: error => {
    if (
      error.response.data.hasOwnProperty("message") &&
      error.response.data.hasOwnProperty("stackHighlighted")
    ) {
      throw new SubmissionError({
        _error: error.response.data.hasOwnProperty("message") || "error"
      });
    } else {
      const errKeys = Object.keys(error.response.data);
      const errObj = {};
      for (const errItem of errKeys) {
        errObj[errItem] = error.response.data[errItem]["message"];
      }

      errObj["_error"] = "Произошла ошибка!";

      throw new SubmissionError(errObj);
    }
  }
};
```

why do I need this in form instead of add component? so I can fix logic with `loading` state variable and re-submit form

also my `_error` isn't working for some reasons, but I've done everything as in doc: https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/submitvalidation/

what I do wrong and how to handle SubmissionError in form component?

Comment: for example: if i write `error => {
        throw new Error({});
      }` - everything is fine, and form component then().catch() goes to catch block, but when i use SubmissionError - it goes to then (like promise was ok, but it wasn't!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your error handling is not working is because you should throw new `SubmissionError` in the `handleSubmit` function itself, [like the example you linked](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/submitvalidation/):

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>

function submit(values) {
  return sleep(1000).then(() => {
    // If error
    throw new SubmissionError({
      password: 'Wrong password',
      _error: 'Login failed!'
    })

    // The rest logic here ...
  })
}
```

So you should refactor your code a little bit, something like that (follow the comments):

```
<form className={formClassNames} onSubmit={handleSubmit(values => {
 // 1. Your submit logic should be here.
 // 2. Better to organize it in a stand-alone function, as `submit` function from the above example.
 // 3. If you throw SubmissionError here, the error handling will work.
 throw new SubmissionError({
   _error: 'Error'
 })
)}>
```

Try to tune-up and simplify your code, like the official library example you provided.

---

**Update 1 - almost a complete example**. Please follows the comments strictly:

* *I removed some unrelated to the problem code blocks*

**TractorForm** - it will be reused for both *Edit* and *Add* (Create) actions.

```
class TractorForm extends Component {

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, error } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        // Rest input fields should be here ...

        { error && (
          <div className="ui red message">
            <strong>{error}</strong>
          </div>
        )}

        <div className="ui fluid buttons">
          <button
            className="ui primary button"
            type="submit"
            disabled={loading}
          >
            {submitText}
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: "tractor"
})(TractorForm);
```

**TractorAdd** - For adding a new Tractor. The same logic, you can apply for Edit Tractor. You have to create a new `TractorEdit` component, that will pass down `onSubmit` function to `TractorForm`.

```
class TractorAdd extends Component {

  onSubmit (values) {
    // Please make sure here you return the promise result. It's a `redux-form` gotcha.
    // If you don't return it, error handling won't work.
    return TractorApi.create(values).then(
      () => {
        toast({
          type: "success",
          icon: "truck",
          title: "Тягач создан",
          description: ""
        });
        this.props.history.push("/tractors");
      },
      error => {
        // 1. Here you should throw new SubmissionError.
        // 2. You should normalize the error, using some parts of `ErrorHandler` function
        throw new SubmissionError(error)
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <TractorForm onSubmit={this.onSubmit} submitText="Создать" />
    </div>
  }
}

export default TractorAdd;
```

---

**Update 2 - keep you implementation as it is, but change a little bit your `TractorFormWrapper` `onFormSubmit` and its usage:**

Documentation explanations [here](https://redux-form.com/7.1.0/docs/faq/handlevson.md/).

**TractorForm**

```
class TractorFormWrapper extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: false,
    isSubmitted: false
  };

  onFormSubmit = data => {

    this.setState({ isSubmitted: true });
    if (this.props.valid) {
      this.setState({ loading: true });

      // `onSubmit` comes from `TractorAdd`
      return this.props.onSubmit(data)
        .then(() => alert("is ok!"))
        .catch(err => {
          return ErrorHandler.raiseAnError(err);
        });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props

    return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onFormSubmit)}>The rest logic is here ...</form>
  }
}

let TractorForm = {};

TractorForm.propTypes = {
  submitText: PropTypes.string
};

TractorForm.defaultProps = {
  submitText: "Отправить"
};

TractorForm = reduxForm({
  form: "tractor"
})(TractorFormWrapper);

export default TractorForm;
```

Comment: ok, but how to `this.props
        .handleSubmit(e)
        .then(() => alert("is ok!"))
        .catch(err => {
          return ErrorHandler.raiseAnError(err);
        });` get into catch here?

Comment: also it's an extremely bad idea: to have the same code form edit & add in the form component: that's why I'm using `formAdd` component and 'nested' `form` component: form is isolated, and server calls are in another logic component

Comment: I added almost a complete example. Please follow the idea of my answer's feedback and the example I provided for you.

Comment: thank you, but still you are missing an extremelly important part: `handleSubmit` is not redifened in form component => I can't add ui spinner-loader && disable button.

Comment: `onFormSubmit=e=> { e.preventDefault(); this.setState({ isSubmitted: true }); // so I can display error messages only when I clicked on submit button if (this.props.valid) { // form is valid? let's send it to the server, not when it's invalid this.setState({ loading: true }); // let's display spinner this.props .handleSubmit(e) .then(() => alert("is ok!")) // here we have to hide spinner and do nothing else... .catch(err => { return ErrorHandler.raiseAnError(err); // here we have to hide spinner and do something else if needed in the future, but it's always going into .then block :() }); } };`

Comment: In *TractorAdd* ->`onSubmit` function you can validate your form, before triggering Server API call with `TractorApi`. About the spinner and other flags, `redux-form` provide them for you, so you shouldn't create your own implementation. For example you have `submitting` (Whether or not your form is currently submitting.). https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/props.md/

Comment: That's the flow I'm following in my projects and it completely follows and respects the `redux-form` documentation. Here's official library example, that's the same as my example: https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/simple/ + https://codesandbox.io/s/mZRjw05yp

Comment: So please try to implement and follow my example - and you'll see that the error handling will work which is the main problem of your question.

Comment: `submitting` is ok! but not `submitted`
that's the problem :)
I have to check was it submitted or not
and moving it to the top level component like ..Add - is not a good idea seems to me.

Comment: @brabertaser19 you can do it directly in the `TractorForm` as follows: `<form onSubmit={data => handleSubmit(data).then(() => { // HERE YOU CAN UPDATE YOUR COMPONENT STATE })}>`

Comment: @brabertaser19 I added another approach (Update 2) how you can handle it without refactoring too much your current implementation. Please focus on `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onFormSubmit)}>`.

Comment: I forgot to return the Promise in onFormSubmit: `return this.props.onSubmit(data)`. Now it should print the errors. Updated my example.

Comment: I can get such errors like this? `{this.props.error}` ? strange.. can't print them
also i refactored code to first update :)))

Comment: If you still have an issue then please create a minimum working example, that illustrates the problem in Codepen or here and I will check what's the problem. Something like this one: https://codesandbox.io/s/mZRjw05yp

Comment: Hey. Are there any other issues related to the question? If yes - please provide a working sandbox example and I will try to support you (not an archive or raw files). If they aren't related, please open a new question. Thanks!